# How do I correct an error on my submitted IMM 5710E form for my Canadian Post Graduate Work Permit Application?

Tags: working-visas, canada, student-visa, paperwork

I would like some urgent advice. I recently submitted my PGWP application (on the 8th of May) to IRCC, I applied online. I am yet to hear back from them. However, I realized that I have made an error on my IMM5710E form. Instead of entering the Document Number for my study permit, I entered the document number for my TRV.

I do have a copy of my study permit attached to my application and both my UID and TRV Document Numbers are accurate (I triple checked), but I am concerned that because I entered the TRV document number instead of the Study Permit document number my application may be denied (or delayed).

This is in response to Question 4 (If possible, provide the document number of your most recent Visitor Record, Study Permit, Work Permit or Temporary Resident Permit issued to you" of the section "COMING INTO CANADA" in the IMM5710 E form.

In your opinion, do you think I should reach out to CIC and petition them to update my application with the document number for the study permit? How would you suggest I do that? Or should I wait for them to respond?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options here:

- **[Call CIC](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/contacts/call.asp)** and ask them what's the procedure to change that information (be very specific while doing this). They will send you instructions via email
- Alternatively you can fill out **[this form](https://secure.cic.gc.ca/enquiries-renseignements/canada-case-cas-eng.aspx#contentPlaceHolderMainContent_tbEnquiry)** and explain them inside, the mistake you did. (This one might take a little more time)